# Flask: Bad Request POST 400

Tags: python, flask

I use flask and firebase. I have 2 button in satis.html . When user press button2 , i want to retrieve some data from database and show it. But i get " Bad Request " Error.

Heres my code :

```
@app.route('/satis', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def satis():
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
                sehir=request.form['il']
                yas=request.form['yas']
                id=request.form['id']
                gun=request.form['satisgunu']
                cins=request.form['cinsiyet']
                tarz=request.form['satistarzi']
                db = firebase.database()
                db.child("names").push({"sehir": sehir,"yas":yas,"id":id,"gun":gun,"cins":cins,"tarz":tarz})
                todo = db.child("names").get()
                to = todo.val()
                if request.form['submit'] == 'add':
                    db = firebase.database()
                    users_by_score = db.child("names").order_by_child("id").equal_to("2").get()
                    us = users_by_score.val()
                    return render_template('satis.html', t=to.values(),u=us.values())
                return render_template('satis.html', t=to.values())
```

Comment: if (request.method == 'POST'), remove this, pass the data in the URL. Make a get request and see what is happening. You will get the error message.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not coment) as text (not screenshot). There are other usful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only handled for post method. You need to also handle the GET method situation.

```
@app.route('/satis', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def satis():
    db = firebase.database()
    todo = db.child("names").get()
    to = todo.val()
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
                sehir=request.form['il']
                yas=request.form['yas']
                id=request.form['id']
                gun=request.form['satisgunu']
                cins=request.form['cinsiyet']
                tarz=request.form['satistarzi']
                db.child("names").push({"sehir": sehir,"yas":yas,"id":id,"gun":gun,"cins":cins,"tarz":tarz})
                if request.form['submit'] == 'add':
                    db = firebase.database()
                    users_by_score = db.child("names").order_by_child("id").equal_to("2").get()
                    us = users_by_score.val()
                    return render_template('satis.html', t=to.values(),u=us.values())
    return render_template('satis.html', t=to.values())
```